# Create HTTPS server with node js

Tags: node.js, https

I want to create a https server for my localhost.
Node JS documentation provides out of the box solution but I have some confusion with it.
**Example**

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('test/fixtures/keys/agent2-key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('test/fixtures/keys/agent2-cert.pem')
};

https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end("hello world\n");
}).listen(8000);
```

**Or**

```
var options = {
  pfx: fs.readFileSync('server.pfx')
};
```

Here how would I get key, cert or pfx for my localhost?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

For development purposes you can create a self-certified certificate.
Here's how to do it on a linux-based system:

First, generate a private key

```
openssl genrsa 1024 > key.pem
```

This will store a 1024 bit RSA key in the file key.pem

Then, generate an SSL certificate with that key:

```
openssl req -x509 -new -key key.pem > key-cert.pem
```

Now, you can use key.pem and key-cert.pem in the options you pass to createServer.

Answer (score 2):

the `.pfx` file is a "bundle" maded of the `key.pem` , `cert.pem` and sometimes a (`CA file`) files.

You should get(pay) / [make](http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html)(testing etc) a https certificate.

Answer (score 0):

This is called **self-signed certificate**, and you can generate it with one command by openssl. Just type:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -new -nodes -x509 -days 3650 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem
```

in the terminal.