# Unable to create HTTPS server with node.js

Tags: node.js, https, server

I'm trying to create an HTTPS server using node.js and I created one following [Create HTTPS server with node js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16610612/create-https-server-with-node-js) and using that to create my key and cert.

However, when I run my code and try to load `localhost:8080`, the page takes forever to load, and the page ends up saying

```
No data received

ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

If I use HTTP, the page loads fine. Here is my code to create the server:

```
var https = require('https')
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('key-cert.pem')
};

var server = https.createServer(options, function(req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 
    ...
)};

server.listen(8080);
```

I was wondering why this isn't working and how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: `localhost:8080` isn't a URL, the scheme is missing. What did you actually type?

Comment: i'm not sure i completely understand what you mean by the scheme is missing. I entered localhost:8080 in the browser, which works when I use HTTP, instead of HTTPS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i'm not sure i completely understand what you mean by the scheme is missing. I entered localhost:8080 in the browser, which works when I use HTTP, instead of HTTPS

URLs must have a scheme. When you don't type a scheme, the browser assumes you are going to use HTTP and adds `http://` for you. (Sadly, modern browsers then promptly don't display that in the address bar.)

So by typing `localhost:8080` you visit `http://localhost:8080` which doesn't work because the service listening on that port is running SSL, not HTTP.

You need to type `https://localhost:8080`.

Comment: thanks, that worked. turns out Chrome didn't like my certificate, but it works on Firefox, so I just need to get Chrome to accept my certificate.

Answer (score 0):

From the code you've shown, it appears the reason your request is timing out (and nothing shows up) is because you aren't actually writing any content to the page. You've got `...` there (which maybe means you've got lots more code that does it) but if not, try:

```
var https = require('https')
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('key-cert.pem')
};

var server = https.createServer(options, function(req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 
    res.end(JSON.stringify({hello: "world"})); 
)};

server.listen(8080);
```

Comment: I do have more code in there, but I just tried what you suggested and it didn't seem to work either. I put a `console.log` before `res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'); ` and nothing printed, so it seems like the code is not running through there for whatever reason..