# Switch webRTC from http to https

Tags: node.js, http, webrtc

I'm using this [tutorial](https://bitbucket.org/webrtc/codelab) to learn how [webRTC](https://webrtc.org/) works (I'm quite new with that); however, from december 2015 http server are deprecated in chrome/chromium, and only https connections are accepted.

I'm at step2[can't link because of my reputation] of this tutorial.

I need to switch to https (so webRTC can work in all browsers), but I can't find any way to do that.

Anyone has some sort of ideas to do that?

Comment: According to your node.js tag, you'll have some answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16610612/create-https-server-with-node-js)

Comment: thanks, it works now!