# Create an HTTPS server with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, https

I'm getting error while trying to access HTTPS server I created with NodeJS.

What do I do :

1.First of all : [generate a self-signed certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5U2F.png) :

```
openssl genrsa -out key.pem
openssl req -new -key key.pem -out csr.pem
openssl x509 -req -days 9999 -in csr.pem -signkey key.pem -out cert.pem
```

2.Create simple NodeJs Https server -

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');
var server_port = 8080;

var httpsOptions = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('\key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('\cert.pem')
};

var app = function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end("hello world\n");
}   
https.createServer(httpsOptions, app).listen(server_port);
```

3. run the server : node main.js (the file name)
   The server is running but when I try access https://localhost:8080
4. Connect to the server. The result is:

[image]

Comment: Since the server is self signed, the browser will cry. You will need to add the cert to the trust store of the browser.

Comment: @NehalJWani does this still apply for a production server?  I'm curious about self-signing certs

Comment: @sova For public facing production servers, you have to either buys certificates or, get free ones from letsencrypt or startcom.

Comment: @Nehal J Wani : And how do I do that ?

Comment: The certificate is probably malformed since its being used in a browser. Also see [How do you sign Certificate Signing Request with your Certification Authority](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21340898/608639) and [How to create a self-signed certificate with openssl?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10175812/608639) It provides a lot of background information on X.509 server certificates, how to present names, and where the various rules come from.

Comment: Also see [How to create an HTTPS server in Node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5998694), [Create HTTPS server with node js](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16610612). I'm guessing the answers have already been provided to you, except for the certificate hostnames.

Comment: Thanks @jww  I solved the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with:

`openssl genrsa -out key.pem 1024`

or

`openssl genrsa -out key.pem 2048`

A key size of 512 is considered weak

Comment: node raise `Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::xxxx` if port used by another application

Answer (score 2):

Probably this port used by another application (e.g skype). Try another port.